# keras' preprocess_input led to ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, regression

I'm using keras for a regression model. I'm trying to fine tune the VGG16. Everything was working. After I added the `tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input` to preprocess the images according to the VGG16 I got the following error :

> ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
> x sizes: 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
> y sizes: 422
> Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.

After loading the images, I loop through theme and apply this:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array

images = []
for img in loaded_images:
    img = img_to_array(img)
    img = img.reshape((1, img.shape[0], img.shape[1], img.shape[2]))
    img = preprocess_input(img)
    images.append(img)

actual = actual.reshape(1,-1)
assert len(images) == len(actual)
```

After that I partition the images into train, valid and testing set as follows:

**Edit**:

```
train_images,test_images, train_actual_score , test_actual_score = train_test_split(images, scaled_train_mos, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)
```

Finally I call the `fit` func :

```
history = model.fit(x=train_images, y=train_actual_score, validation_data=(test_images, test_actual_score), epochs=30, batch_size=8, verbose=2)
```

**Update**:

Here is a [standalone code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_yqIkVU4H9b8k-sMPGf-FjH7Dzy6s7PO?usp=sharing) to reproduce the above issue.

Comment: Can you add a standalone code to reproduce this issue? Use generated data for your images.

Comment: @AniketBote, what do you mean exactly? which part of the code?

Comment: A code which I can run on my system without having to download any data that will reproduce your error.

Comment: @AniketBote I created a colab, here is the link https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_yqIkVU4H9b8k-sMPGf-FjH7Dzy6s7PO?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few changes that I did to your code in order to make it work:

**1st:**
In generating your random data you were generating img of size (244,24,3) however your model takes input as (224,224,3)

```
# original
im = np.random.randint(0,255,(244,244,3)) 
# changes
im = np.random.randint(0,255,(224,224,3))
```

**2nd:**
Changed reshape function:

```
# Original
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
images_ = []
for img in images:
    img = img_to_array(img)
    img = img.reshape(1, img.shape[0], img.shape[1], img.shape[2])
    img = preprocess_input(img)
    images_.append(img)
# changed
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array

images_ = []
for img in images:
    img = img_to_array(img)
    img = img.reshape(img.shape[0], img.shape[1], img.shape[2])
    img = preprocess_input(img)
    images_.append(img)
```

The reshape method you used was generating (50, 1, 244, 244, 3) which is not correct. Although I'm not sure why you used the reshape in the first place since your data is already in the correct format.

**3rd:**
You reshape the scores into shape (1,50) which means your training data contains only 1 sample and 50 values. There is no need to change the shape of scores. (50,1) is the correct shape representing you have 50 samples and  prediction value.

**4th:**
Converted the list to numpy array:

```
train_images = np.array(train_images)
test_images = np.array(test_images)
train_score = np.array(train_score)
test_score = np.array(test_score)
```

See the full working code [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FB6wLO7y9f2w5eYmGFkZbVaYQgrY32XR?usp=sharing)

Comment: Actually it's the same as the one I gave, it's maybe the naming is not quite clear. I swipe the `x` and `y`  and the same error occurred. As I mentioned, the code was working, the error occurred only after I added the `preprocess_input` .